# Pause and Resume CLLocation tracking in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocation

How to pause and resume the location tracking? I have developed code for location tracking, but i want it to pause and not stop, and then resume, so that my distance calculation continues.
(Pause and resume is activated by UIButtons)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about CLLocationManager, no, you can't pause it. You can, however,  set a large distance filter. According to WWDC 2010 video for core location, this will reduce the  resources being consumed by the location services.

Comment: How do we use large distance filters?

Comment: [yourLocationManager setDistanceFilter:k_LARGE_CONSTANT_VALUE]; just assign a value you are comfortable with.

Comment: Will this help me in pausing and resuming?

Comment: No. Like I said, there is no such thing as pausing/resuming a CLLocationManager. There is starting and stopping. What this will do is that it will work as a low power mode, and will probably not deliver a location update unless the user moves a significant distance.